# Pasar parámetros de label a ReportViewer c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, reportviewer, report

Buenas he intentado pasar el valor que tengo en un label a un reportViewer de la siguiente manera:

Creo el parámetro prueba:

[image: Creo el parámetro prueba]

Introduzco el parámetro en un cuadro de texto en el reporte

[image: lo introduzco en el reporte1.rdlc]

Creo el siguiente código en el Form_load

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        ReportParameter prueba = new ReportParameter("label.text");
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { prueba });
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh(); 

        }
```

Y cuando ejecuto el programa el reporte me muestra lo siguiente: falta un valor en el parámetro prueba

[image: el reporte no carga]

También he intentado asignarle un texto al parámetro obteniendo el mismo resultado, de la siguiente manera:

```
 ReportParameter prueba = new ReportParameter("prueba");
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { prueba });
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En su mensaje en el visor de Informes, le dice que "Falta el valor para el parámetro prueba", entonces al igual como hace, establezca el/los parámetros utilizando la propiedad `LocalReport` en el Visor de informes, especificando el nombre del parámetro y el valor del mismo, de la siguiente manera:

```
ReportParameter prueba = new ReportParameter("prueba", label.text);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { prueba });
```

o con una colección de parámetros:

```
ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("NombreParametro", "Valor"));
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```